# Why Blazor Component runs at least 2 times?

Tags: blazor

Why the Blazor codes will run 2 times for loading and button clicked?
index.cshtml file:

```
    @model Movies.Models.Department[]
    @using Movies.Component


<div class="text-center">
    //some codes here
</div>

@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<DepartmentList>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

DepartmentList.razor file:

```
<div>
    Hello, now is <span>@Display_DateTime()</span>
    <div>
        <button @onclick="(e => Display_DateTime())">
            Display computer date and time. 
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    string Display_DateTime()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        return now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you. It runs once only during the component calling. I still getting twice execution when the button is clicked and the code session is trigger. It cannot give me the first DateTime.Now data.

Comment: Didn't you see my answer which I deleted? It told you what was the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, I did changed to Render.Server. However, when I click the button for getting the current system date time, it runs twice. It should run only once for the button clicked.